# Adding double* to double variable

Tags: c, pointers, struct, double

I am currently working on a program that gets your name, address, school marks etc. as input and has to calculate the average mark of f.e. the subject APHM.

Can anybody explain why using a pointer to add a value into a variable won't work?

Thanks in advance!

```
double avgINF=0, avgAPHM=0, ...;

struct adresse{
            char vorname[50];
            char nachname[50];
            char strasse[50];
            char hausnr[50];
            char tuer[10];
            char ort[50];
            char plz[10];
            double noteAPHM[1];
            double noteINF[1];
        } adressen[41];

avgINF += adressen[i-1].noteINF;
```

Error: Invalid operands to binary expression (double*)

Comment: `noteINF[1]` why on earth!?

Comment: Because it is a very, very bad idea?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the site!  If `noteINF` is supposed to only hold one value, it should be `double noteINF;` rather than `double noteINF[1];`.  For single values you don't need an array (`[1]` suffix).

As to your error message, `noteINF[1]` is an array.  In the context of your code above, the name of an array behaves as a pointer to the first element of the array.  So `noteINF` behaves as a `double *` (pointer to double) and `noteINF[0]` is a `double` (the first element of the array).  There are lots of tutorials online regarding C arrays and pointers, since almost everyone trips over them at some point.  Good luck!

Comment: Thanks!

It seems that I forgot to delete the array definition after redefining it from char[] to double...

Comment: I would like to, it says I have to wait another 4 minutes, but of course I am going to :)

Comment: "the name of an array is a pointer to the first element of the array" - Arrgggg! **Wrong**!

Comment: Adding up to *Olaf*, the phrase in question should read "*Arrays under certain conditions decay to a pointer to their 1st element.*" They however definitely "*are*" ***not*** pointers, as an array is an array is an array and is not a pointer.

Comment: And BTW, compiled C code does not know nothing about variable's "*name*"s.

Comment: Why does an image of Bart Simpson with one of his typical statements just showed up?

Comment: @Olaf I'm sorry to say I don't know what you mean.  In any event, I edited the answer to change "In C" to "In context."

Comment: If you see that carttons, you should know (not sure if he say it that often in the newer seasons, though). Anyway, you got the correct phrase from @alk or can use the one from the standard (there is only one!). The edit has now some grammar issues which can still read wrong.